# I am using CATiledLayer and UIScrollView, how can I dynamically set CATiledLayer properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, core-animation

Basically speaking I am making a map framework (like Route-me and Google Maps). I want to change some properties of CATiledLayers which are not documented. So I dont know if it is possible:

I want to dynamically set properties of CATiledLayer, such as layer size, tile numbers, what conditions to trigger reloading tile source, and binding a function when CATiledLayer realoding sources?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would think that it is not documented, aren't you referring to the things below?

Dynamically set properties of CATiledLayer, such as layer size, tile numbers

```
  tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = ...
  tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = ...
  tiledLayer.frame = ...
```

What conditions to trigger reloading tile source -> You should be able to call `-setNeedsDisplay` to trigger reload when you want to.

Binding a function when CATiledLayer realoding sources -> Implement `-drawLayer:inContext:` in a delegate